# How to tune the formatting options of the Delphi IDE so that there is no newline after the VAR keyword?

Tags: delphi, formatting, pretty-print

By default, when you press <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, the Delphi IDE always adds a newline after the `VAR` keyword. It looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to let Delphi format my code so that there was no newline after the `VAR` keyword? The expected result should look that like this.
[image]

Comment: In a word - no.  The *compiler* supports inline variables, but the *IDE* (code completion, code formatting, etc) hasn't really caught up to that feature yet.  So using inline variables causes all kinds of issues for automated tools